# Neo4j automate graph change over time

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way (query) or tools that enable auto playback of a graph change over time?

E.g. over time, new nodes or old nodes might be removed.

For instance:

- Graph 1: Node A is connected to 4 others nodes
- Graph 2: Node A is connected to 3 others nodes
- Graph 3: Node A is connected to 6 others nodes

A "playback" or query to automatically shows Graph 1 to 3 periodically.

Any suggestion is appreciated! :)

Comment: If you want to know what has been changed to the graph, you might want to hook at the transaction. or maybe use the neo4j-changefeed module : https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-changefeed

Comment: Another (possibly different) suggestion:  you can timestamp all nodes and relationships, then do iterative queries based on a time window.  What was created last week?  OK, now show that, plus what was create this week, etc.    See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682598/how-to-return-all-newest-nodes-from-neo4j

Comment: This is also related to versioning of graphs, like these: http://iansrobinson.com/2014/05/13/time-based-versioned-graphs/ http://de.slideshare.net/ophileon/graphrica-keeping-track-of-changes-in-project-logic-for-de

Comment: There are no official tools for it, but there are internal APIs for scanning Neo4j's transaction logs and determining the change-commands.

Comment: And there is the keylines timebar which can be integrated with Neo4j: keylines.com/network-visualization/visualize-neo4j-time-graph

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options how to deal with your problem.

1. Write your own Unmanaged Extension which will use Transaction API and log those information by yourself

   - http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.0/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html
   - http://graphaware.com/neo4j/transactions/2014/07/11/neo4j-transaction-event-api.html
2. This extension for Neo4j could be interestion for you

   - https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-changefeed
3. Time-Based Versioned Graphs

   - http://gist.neo4j.org/?608bf0701e3306a23e77